# How can i change the colors and appearance of my node.js calculator?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, pug

im using node js w express and jade
i cant get my calculator to look anything but bland colors even after changing the css and layout.   I am not sure if i should edit the css file or a different one

index.jade

```
    extends layout

block content
  h1= title
 p Welcome to #{title}
  p hello this is my calculator
  form(name='Calc')
   table(border='4')
    tr
      td
        input(type='text', name='Input', size='22')
        br
    tr
      td
            input(type='button', name='one', value='  1  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value +=       \'1\'')
        input(type='button', name='two', value='  2  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \'2\'')
        input(type='button', name='three', value='  3  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \'3\'')
        input(type='button', name='plus', value='  +  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \' + \'')
        br
        input(type='button', name='four', value='  4  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \'4\'')
        input(type='button', name='five', value='  5  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \'5\'')
        input(type='button', name='six', value='  6  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \'6\'')
        input(type='button', name='minus', value='  -  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \' - \'')
        br
        input(type='button', name='seven', value='  7  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \'7\'')
        input(type='button', name='eight', value='  8  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \'8\'')
        input(type='button', name='nine', value='  9  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \'9\'')
        input(type='button', name='times', value='  x  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \' * \'')
        br
        input(type='button', name='clear', value='  c  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value = \'\'')
        input(type='button', name='zero', value='  0  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \'0\'')
        input(type='button', name='DoIt', value='  =  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value = eval(Calc.Input.value)')
        input(type='button', name='div', value='  /  ', onclick='Calc.Input.value += \' / \'')
        br
```

layout.jade

```
    doctype html
html
  head
title= title
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
 body
  block content
```

styles.css

```
    body {
 font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
 a {
  color: #00b7ff;
 }
```

app.js

```
      var express = require('express');
    var routes = require('./routes');
      var user = require('./routes/user');
    var http = require('http');
     var path = require('path');

    var app = express();

   // all environments
   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
   app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
       app.use(express.favicon());
   app.use(express.logger('dev'));
   app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
   app.use(app.router);
     app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

       // development only
        if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
           app.use(express.errorHandler());
        }

         app.get('/', routes.index);
         app.get('/users', user.list);

             http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
```

Comment: (This probably isn't a solution) I'd remove the stylus middleware, as you're not using it `app.use(require('stylus')...`. I'm pretty sure that it replaces your .css files with a compiled version from the .styl files periodically.

Comment: i have a .styl  file as well but it looks just like the layout

Comment: Stylus is a CSS preprocessor made by TJ Holowaychuk (same dude who made Express and Jade). If you're using Stylus, you should go all in on stylus (edit only `.styl` files and not `.css`). Note that regular CSS is also valid Stylus markup. As for styling the calculator, you should open it in Firebug or Chrome Web Dev Tools and play around with the style panes; Once your webapp reaches the browser, it doesn't matter that it's a NodeJS app when you're styling it.

Comment: Also, it might be beneficial to anybody trying to help you answer this question if you provide perhaps the output HTML when you load your page (perhaps in a JSFiddle along with the CSS, if not, include a screenshot of its current state) as well as a description/screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is styling 'a' tags, but I don't see any links in your html.

Give your elements a class, and then style that class using CSS.

Comment: how should i go about doing that